# $a_n = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Bruckner & Bruckner, Elements of Real Analysis.

> Let $$a,b > 0 $$
>   $$a_1 = a,   a_2 = b $$ and
>   $$a_{n+2} = \frac12(a_{n+1} + a_{n})$$
>   Prove that the even numbered subsequence and odd numbered subsequence are both monotonic and both converge.

Suppose a < b. Then I've to prove that
$$a_{2n+2} < a_{2n} $$

$$\frac12a_{2n+1} < \frac12a_{2n}$$ 
Can't really work any of this out.

Comment: Look at $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$.

Comment: Solve the difference equation, you then obtain $a_{2n+2}-a_{2n}=\frac{a-b}{2^{2n}}$ and $a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}=2\frac{a-b}{2^{2n}}$.

Comment: Thank you for that. I kept trying to solve it by manipulating the inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $a< b$ $(a = a_1, b = a_2)$

$a_1<a_2$ then $a_3 = \frac{a+b}{2}$ and   $a_1< a_3 <a_2$

similarly $a_4 = \frac{a_2+a_3}{2}$ is such that $a_3< a_4 < a_2$

therefore $a_1< a_3 <a_4 < a_2$

repeat this argument you will have $$ a_1< a_3 < \ldots <a_{2n +1}< \ldots$$
 and
$$ a_2> a_4 > \ldots >a_{2n }> \ldots$$

The other case ($a>b$) is analogous.