# Given $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, and $a_n = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})$ for $n>2$, prove bounded by 1 and 2

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, cauchy-sequences

I attempted using induction to prove it formally but was not sure how to proceed.

Additionally, how can you prove the sequence is neither monotonically increasing nor decreasing?

Comment: what did you try? one typical approach when proving something hold for all $n$ could be induction :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330605, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1928249, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276402, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/502100, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1451455, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514083

Answer (score 1):

After checking of the base and after assuming of the induction we obtain the following.

For all $n\geq3$ we have
$$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}\geq\frac{1+1}{2}=1.$$
Also, for all $n\geq3$ we have:
$$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}\leq\frac{2+2}{2}=2.$$
Done!

Comment: To argue this formally you would have to use induction, but yeah this is a general idea.